# Show a series of activities within another activity? Or should I just use fragments? (Android)

Tags: android, android-fragments

In my app currently, a series of activities are shown after the user presses a button. In each one they fill out some information, then go to the next one. In the last one, the app needs to find their location. I have been considering redesigning it so that it searches for the users location the entire time they are filling out the information in order to get a better read on their location. The problem is in my implementation now, each activity just starts another activity so I can only look for their location on the last one. Because each activity might only last for a second (They are typically just moving a slider or pressing a button) the app doesn't always read their location quickly enough.

Can I use custom views or something to show each activity while running code in a master activity? Or should I run fragments inside of an activity and run the location code in the main activity? I am still fairly new to android so I apologize if there is a simple way I should be doing this. Thanks!

Comment: In your case, if the activities serve a shared purpose (questionnaire/registration form), then Fragments definitely make more sense.

Comment: Background location search does not have to be bound to specific activity. Just use singleton with separate thread which publishes result and finished event.

Answer (score 1):

I recommended you to use a **ViewPager** widget within your activity and to populate this ViewPager with a series of **Fragments** to show your steps. Then you can use the time the user expends passing ViewPager steps to grab user location from ViewPager holder MainActivity.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer. What would be the advantage to using a ViewPager instead of just the fragment manager? Would it just be with the animations?

Comment: @JackLoth It is just a personal recommendation, of course, you can use fragment transaction to manage your fragment "manually" but has more sense to use a ViewPager because it is the widget designed for that kind of behavior

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's any one ideal flow for this. Your problem could be solved if you get the location in a `Service`. Run it in a Service in which each Activity can bind to so they get the information needed. If you only want the service running when there is an Activity, then you can set it up so the service only lives as long as something is bound to it.  Then, if the user leaves the app the service will shutdown on its own.  Or, you can let the Service run until the location is found.  Save it, then when the user comes back, it'll be ready. You can have some strategy in place so the location will be updated if it is old.